# MySQL query Count in subquery

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I have a question.

I have a table called **event_booking**.
Here we have events and each event has a separate location.

So we have event

*event_booking* has :

1. booking_id
2. booking_name
3. booking_date
4. booking_location
5. booking_comments

The type of structure is :

- booking_id = integer
- booking_name = varchar
- booking_date = datetime
- booking_location = integer
- booking_comments = text

Now I want to create a Query that lists all event locations and for each location which event has been set there.

So :

I would get a result like :

1. booking_location = 4 & no_bookings = 256
2. booking_location = 7 & no_bookings = 34
3. booking_location = 6 & no_bookings = 128
4. booking_location = 3 & no_bookings = 24

Now I have fiddled a lit and created the following QUERY.
That's correct in terms of syntax. But totally wrong in terms of output.

```
SELECT `booking_location`, `booking_location` AS `selector`, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `event_booking` WHERE `booking_location` = `selector`) AS `no_bookings` FROM `event_booking` WHERE `booking_location` IN (SELECT `booking_location` FROM `event_booking` GROUP BY `booking_location`)
```

I know I am missing something. But what I am *missing*..
Thanks in advance ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you really just want to count the booking locations (based on your example of a possible result, and also your query code):

```
  SELECT booking_location,
         COUNT(booking_location) AS no_bookings
    FROM event_booking
GROUP BY booking_location;
```